# Sources on the role of the House of Nathan in post-exilic Judah

Tags: zechariah, exile, judah, mourning

I'm researching the biblical references to the "House of Nathan" in Zechariah 12:12 in context of mourning rituals in post-exilic Judah. What extra-biblical sources discuss the identity and potential duties/roles this clan descended from the prophet Nathan may have had?

Specifically, is there any evidence in sources like the Dead Sea Scrolls, Josephus, rabbinic writings, etc. that sheds light on:

How this clan traced its lineage back to Nathan son of David

If they held a recognized position overseeing aspects of mourning/lamentation rituals

Any specialized priestly or musical/literary responsibilities within temple or community worship

Comparisons to other prominent priestly families like Levites, how their influence/duties were defined

Any other details about their identity or place within the religious leadership of Judea after the exile

Any information or directions to relevant sources that could help elucidate this minor but important biblical reference would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question is asking for 'extra-biblical sources' which I suggest is off-topic on an _hermeneutic_ site.

Comment: I gave an answer based on the text. If such a clan actually existed, you would have a better chance finding it at MiYodea.SE than here.

Answer (score 0):

Zech 12

> On that day the mourning in Jerusalem will be as great as the mourning
> for Hadadrimmon in the plain of Megiddo. 12 And the land shall mourn,
> each family apart: the family of the house of David, and their women;
> the family of the house of Nathan, and their women; 13 the family of
> the house of Levi, and their women; the family of Shimei, and their
> women; 14 and all the rest of the families, each family apart, and the
> women apart.

The search for the descendants of the "House of Nathan" may be futile, because the text uses this a symbolic of a class of leader rather than an actual clan. The clans in question are:

- Judean nobility (the House of David)
- Prophets (the House of Nathan)
- Priests (House of Levi)
- Northern nobility (family of Shimei), see 2 Samuel 16:5
- Jewish men in general (the rest of the families)
- Jewish women

The "mourning for Hadadrimmon in the plain of Megiddo" is interpreted by the editors of the NABRE as a reference to public expressions of extreme grief during an annual ritual for a [Phoenician fertility god](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=zech+12&version=NABRE). Other experts interpret it as mourning for King Josiah, who died in battle at Megiddo.

**Conclusion**: This passage does not refer to literal existing clans but key classes of Jewish society: nobility, prophets, priests, and common people. It is a poetic way of telling us that the mourning will be universal.